# Problema com Soma de dados de várias tabelas usando PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, soma

Galera, eu desenvolvi um sistema de chamadas, e agora preciso fazer o relatório dos alunos com a quantidade de faltas e presenças.

Eu uso 1 tabela(`chamadas`) para cadastrar algumas informações da chamada e quando efetua o cadastro, o sistema cria uma tabela(`chamada_XXXXXXXXX`) onde terá os dados dessa chamada, como: o aluno e o status (presença ou falta) do mesmo.

Como o relatório precisa exibir o total de presença e falta de cada aluno, ele tem que acessar cada uma das tabelas(`chamada_XXXXXXXXX`) já criadas (incluídas na tabela `chamadas`) e somar o total final de presença e faltas, e é nessa parte onde estou tendo problema.

Vou deixar um print do banco de dados para vocês entenderem melhor e também o código que estou tentando realizar a consulta e retornar o total.

**TODAS AS TABELAS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**TABELA CHAMADAS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**TABELA (chamada_xxxxxxxxx) COM OS DADOS DA CHAMADA, ALUNO, PRESENÇA E FALTA**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CÓDIGO DE PROCURA DOS ALUNOS E CONTAGEM DE FALTAS E PRESENÇAS**
Esse código ele está me retornando somente de 1 tabela, ou seja, não está somando quando passando por uma nova tabela (1+1+1+1+1....).

```
<?php 
$procura_alunos = $site->query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE curso = '$token' ORDER BY nome ASC");
while ($aluno = $procura_alunos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $procura_chamadas = $chamadas->query("SELECT * FROM chamadas WHERE curso = '$token'");
    while ($chamada = $procura_chamadas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $conta_faltas = $chamadas->query("SELECT * FROM $chamada->tabela WHERE turma = '$aluno->turma' AND alunos = '$aluno->chns' AND status = 'F'");
        $conta_presencas = $chamadas->query("SELECT * FROM $chamada->tabela WHERE turma = '$aluno->turma' AND alunos = '$aluno->chns' AND status = 'C'");
        $faltas = $conta_faltas->rowCount();
        $presencas = $conta_presencas->rowCount();
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $aluno->nome;?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="color: #00ff4e"><strong id="presencas_<?php echo$aluno->id; ?>"><?php echo $presencas;?></strong></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="color: #ef0c0c"><strong id="faltas_<?php echo$aluno->id; ?>"><?php echo $faltas;?></strong></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor usar `JOIN` para fazer isso? [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: você consegue me dar algum exemplo de como eu usaria para fazer a consulta com `JOIN`? Eu nunca mexi com ele então não sei direito como usa-lo nesse caso.

Comment: [Nesse link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) e [neste link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) tem bastante coisa.